# Stale file handle error when deleting files in EFS

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

I am getting this error when I want to delete files from Amazon EFS:

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /OutlookAttachments: Stale file handle
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:88) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.hasNext(FileTreeIterator.java:104) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:115) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
```

Does it mean that the file doesn't exist? If not, what could be the cause?